# One app with multiple apk

Tags: android, apk

I created an application which has different layout for phones and tablets. Can I add my app in two apk on Google Play one for Phones & one for Tablets? I found supports-screens in the documentation but not sure about that. I have to do this because my app is dealing with images and if I merge images for both (phones & tablets) then size of app is very large.

Comment: How large is "very large"? It's quite easy nowadays to find apps in Play with sizes ~30Mb.

Comment: @JoséLuis: I guess you meant 30MB -> "b" stands for "bits", "B" stands for "bytes".

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com Yep. But can't edit anymore.

Comment: yes you can but, try to make single, this is the voice of experience it is very hard to manage later on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible.
I'd recommend to set the name as:
"..." for phone
"... HD" for tablets

I'd also include a link in both descriptions, referring to eachother (so the phone app refers to the HD version and visa versa).

Also, i'd recommend to read this:
http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can target apks to specific device configurations. Here's the documentation on it: http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have single app with multiple APKs. See [Multiple APK support](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html), but unless you really see the difference there like completely different assets which bloats the whole app, then sticking to single binary app helps maintaining it further